# What biblical evidence is there that our spirit only began in this life?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-man, spirit

LDS believe that our spirit was in existence before we are born here on earth. What biblical evidences are there that that is not the case?

> Genesis 2:4 These are the generations of the heavens and of the earth when they were created, in the day that the Lord God made the earth and the heavens, 5 And every plant of the field before it was in the earth, and every herb of the field before it grew: for the Lord God had not caused it to rain upon the earth, and there was not a man to till the ground. (KJV)

This implies that plants and herbs were in exhistance before they were placed on the earth. There also seems to be a double creation with Adam.

> Genesis 1:27 So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.
>   Genesis 2:7 And the Lord God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.

This implies that Adam was created spiritually, like plants and herbs, then created from the dust.

There are also other scriptures that support that man exhisted before this life. For instace Job 38:7, Eccl. 12:7, Jer. 1:5, John 9:2, Romans 8:29.

What evidences are there in the bible that our spirits were not in existence until this life?

Comment: Zechariah 12:1 is the only one that I found in the cannon scriptures but that is also easily explained. it say "The burden of the word of the Lord for Israel, saith the Lord, which stretcheth forth the heavens, and layeth the foundation of the earth, and formeth the spirit of man within him."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any particular verses in the Bible that specify souls do not pre-exist.  As Dick said, you are trying to prove a negative, which is difficult.

However, I did find a verse in the Orthodox Deutero-canonical text (referred to by others as the Apocrypha) that says there is no reincarnation:

> A man indeed killeth through his malice: and the spirit, when it is gone forth, returneth not; neither the soul received up cometh again.
>
> Wisdom of Solomon 16:14

It would stand to reason that if reincarnation is not true because a soul being in the place it goes to after life on earth does not come back to earth, then it follows that a soul simply does not come from there to here - it is a one way trip from here to there.

Answer (score -2):

It is an almost universal view among biblical scholars that there are two distinct creation stories in Genesis, written by two different authors at different times. The first story is in Genesis 1:1-2:4a and was written by an anonymous author now known as the Priestly Source. The second is in Genesis 2:4b-25 and was written by the Yahwist, or 'J Source'. this explains the appearance of a "double creation."

Leon R. Kass says in *The Beginning of Wisdom: Reading Genesis*, at page 55, that pious readers, believing that the text cannot contain contradictions, ignore the major disjunctions between the two creation stories and tend to treat the second story as the fuller, more detailed account of the creation of man (and woman) that the first story simply reported.

Those who do see these disjunctions but believe there is only one creation account in Genesis have to look for explanations consistent with this belief. This is where we find the concept that the first story only tells of a spiritual creation.

In the first story, God is all-powerful and simply speaks things into existence. The second is older and more primitive, and here God can not create living things out of nothing: he creates Adam and each of the animals out of moist earth, then Eve out of Adam's rib. This is not necessary for plants, as they are pre-existing as seeds in the ground, waiting for God to make it rain. This is not because God had only created seeds in the ground in Genesis 1:11 - after all, God said to "bring forth" grass, etc.

Kass says, "Once we recognise the independence of the two creation stories, we are compelled to adopt a critical principle of reading if we mean to understand each story on its own terms." This then means we can not use the first story to speculate that God created us (and presumably the animals also created on day 6) spiritually before creating us out of moist earth. Proving from the Bible that our spirits were not in existence before this life involves proving a negative, which is usually impossible, so we usually have to rely on proving probability. Genesis gives no reason to believe that God created humans as spirits before creating us physically.

Comment: Good answer but doesn't quite explain my question. Your answer shows that the spiritual creation can't be proven by the genesis story but I am looking for evidences against it not just proving my arguments wrong.

Comment: @atherises I didn't know I was proving your arguemnts wrong. In fact, from your question, I was not sure which side you took, only that you were explaining the LDS position as you understood it.  I stated "Proving from the Bible that our spirits were not in existence before this life involves proving a negative, which is usually impossible, so we usually have to rely on proving probability." I was trying to give you useful information as close to proving a negative as we are likely to get.

Comment: Sorry if I came off accusative. I'm looking for specific scriptures that may be evidence against spirits being in exhistance before this life. If there aren't any that's fine but that's what I'm looking for.